# Android Marker Click Function

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I'm looking to create a method that runs when a marker's info box/snippet is clicked. As yet, I can't find anything about this, only the marker. Any help or links as to where I could find some more info?

Comment: Always check the api doc first : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_window_click_events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a method that runs when you click the info window you need to `setOnInfoWindowClickListener`:

```
 map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(args.getTitle());

                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                        if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                        {   
                            if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                    String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                                tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                                for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                                {
                                    String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                    String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                    if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                    {  
                                        task = tmptask;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You've essentially answered a question I was gonna have to ask later as well as the one I asked, so thanks very much for that!

Comment: I will when it allows me to.

Comment: You forgot to return the view in `getInfoContents`

Answer (score 1):

Just set OnInfoWindowClickListener for your Map.

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
       //YOUR CODE
        }
    });
```